# CoreMotion is called on background thread any solution

Tags: ios, swift, background, core-motion

I am currenlty running the following code on an XS Max device

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion
class ViewController: UIViewController {
lazy var core = CMMotionManager()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.core.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.05
        self.core.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!){ (data,error) in
            if let trueData = data {
                self.view.reloadInputViews()

                print(trueData, "x")
            }
    }

}

}
}
```

However i receive the following warning

```
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]
```

Why is it running on background thread. I tried both lazy and var with no success

Comment: You don't want Core Motion updates to be processed on the main queue - The documentation tells you this.  You should dispatch the UI updated onto the main queue.  You probably don't want to do this 20 times a second though.

Comment: I am sorry i couldnot get your point. Do you mean the problem is with my .deviceMotionUpdateInterval being set to 0.05

Comment: You have a couple of problems - The updates from Core Motion are not delivered on the main thread, but you are trying to update your UI, which must happen on the main thread.  You need to explicitly dispatch these updates onto the main thread to eliminate the error message.  However, you probably don't want to update your UI 20 times per second.  Depending on what you are showing you might want to update the UI less frequently, storing the motion data somewhere so that you can process it.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help got what you meant